# In Google Drive SDK, how to make a resumable upload?

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried to make a resumable upload without much success.

I read the https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable page but I can't figure out how to get this "Location" header in the response of the first request.

The API documentation specify that we can make either a POST or a PUT on the first URL, but if I make a PUT, I get a 404, and if I make a POST I get a new file created with no content and no Location header in the response.

Here is my POST query (with a PUT and exactly the same query it returns a 404):

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable
Accept = application/json
Authorization = Bearer xxxxxxxxx
Content-Length = 71
Content-Type = application/json
X-Upload-Content-Length = 10
X-Upload-Content-Type = text/plain

{
    mimeType = "text/plain";
    parents =     (
                {
            id = root;
        }
    );
    title = "test.txt";
}
```

and the response:

```
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Wed, 29 Aug 2012 09:53:15 GMT";
Etag = "\"UlXjrWs5BKksMni8RDMKhlFkHGQ/MTM0NjIzMzk5NTA2MQ\"";
Expires = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = GSE;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";

{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "xxxx",
 "etag": "\"xxxx\"",
 "selfLink": "https://xxxx",
 "webContentLink": "https://xxxx",
 "alternateLink": "https://xxxx",
 "title": "test.txt",
 "mimeType": "text/plain",
 "labels": {
  "starred": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "trashed": false,
  "restricted": false,
  "viewed": true
},
"createdDate": "2012-08-29T09:53:15.200Z",
"modifiedDate": "2012-08-29T09:53:15.061Z",
"modifiedByMeDate": "2012-08-29T09:53:15.061Z",
"lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-08-29T09:53:15.061Z",
"parents": [
{
 "kind": "drive#parentReference",
 "id": "xxxx",
 "selfLink": "https://xxxx",
 "parentLink": "https://xxxx",
 "isRoot": true
}
],
"downloadUrl": "https://xxxx",
"userPermission": {
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"xxxx\"",
  "id": "me",
  "selfLink": "https://xxxx",
  "role": "owner",
  "type": "user"
},
"originalFilename": "test.txt",
"fileExtension": "txt",
"md5Checksum": "xxxx",
"fileSize": "0",
"quotaBytesUsed": "0",
"ownerNames": [
"xxxx"
],
"lastModifyingUserName": "xxxx",
"editable": true,
"writersCanShare": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP Request specified in the *Files Insert* documentation page ( https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) is the following :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

**But it's wrong**. The correct method is specified on the *Upload Files* page (https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable) and is :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable
```

Note the *upload* in the URL. Tricky!